# Isotonic water in the morning?

Tags: metabolism, water, sweat

I am building mass and drinking about 3-5 liters water daily. 
I sweat much so I lose much minerals particularly when doing any sport. 
If I drink tap water during sport, I start to feel very weak. 
So I drink isotonic water instead (3 tea spoons of salt and 4 tea spoon of sugar per liter of water).

I started to think if isotonic water is also better to start your metabolism and support your immune system. 
I drink every morning normally one liter of tap water, take 400 mg magnesium, take 20 mg proteins, and walk 15-25 minutes in nature before doing anything else.
I have an intuition that isotonic water can also be better in starting your morning.

I think what is the appropriate type of water for you depends on your amount of sweating generally. 
So I think for me isotonic water is better in the morning too.

**Is isotonic water better in a person sweating much generally?**

**What do you think about isotonic water in starting your morning?**

Comment: 4 teaspoons of sugar would not be a good way for me to start the day.

Comment: @BackInShapeBuddy Less both?

Comment: sorry I don't understand your question, "Less both?"

Comment: I think 4 tea spoon and 1 tea spoon salt is better combination for isotonic drink. Yes, I agree with you that not the best way to start the day - only during training.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isotonic drinks really have nothing to do with your metabolism or immune system. It's just water with solutes in it. As you noted above, salt and sugar are the two most common. The salt helps you retain the water. The sugar provides calories and, by some reports, produces a slight performance boost due to the taste of sugar (studies seem to indicate that it works even with artificial sweeteners or with people who swish the sugar water around and then spit it out).

Isotonic water can be useful if you're sweating heavily, as it can replace the salts you're losing at the same time that you're also hydrating yourself. Good on you for not buying into the pseudoscience hokum of the sports drinks companies. That said, I see no particular need for it unless you're heavily exerting yourself in a situation where you're sweating heavily. Most mornings, I haven't had a chance to do that yet, and I've done nothing to dehydrate myself overnight, so a small glass of tap water does just fine.